# Showing a pound sign in Flash from XML file

Tags: xml, flash

I've downloaded a template flash slideshow, and the client want's to display a price on the text the appears with the pictures. No problem I thought. Dollar signs work fine, but pound signs, no. Reading round on the net, this has something to do with embedded fonts ?

I emailed the developer who said I needed to add the pound sign to the text fields in the source file. Ok so I look through the source file, I can see one thing that looks like a text field. Forums say choose properties and the should be a font's dropdown.

I'm not seeing any font drop down. Going nuts

Any one able to help ?

Rich ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the `TextField` and open the properties tab. If you do not see a bunch of text-related properties (such as Font family, style, Paragraph format etc) then what you selected is not a TextField, maybe a MovieClip containing one, so get inside it (double click) and look for the TextField there.

Anyways, when you have the TextField selected, next to the property "Style" you'll see a button that reads "Embed...", click there and you'll see a pop up screen. There, on the text area labelled "also include these characters" add the pound sign. If you are not using Flash CS5 (or higher) make sure to do this for every single text field in which you need the pound sign (yes, it is a big pain sometimes).

Hope this helps!

Comment: sounds simple enough, I'm just not finding the textfield I think.. I'll keep hunting, thanks

Comment: Yeah, depending on the MovieClip hierarchy, sometimes it can be really difficult to find stuff on Flash... Your on the hands of your Flash designer at the moment (shudder)

Comment: if you knew what font was used, Edit/Find and Replace can allow you to search for that specific font (textfields that use it). It should be easy to locate that way...

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the pound symbol as `&#163;`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign